# ManyToMany assoicate delete join table entry

Tags: hibernate, spring, many-to-many

I use these two entities to create a new user and groups it associates:

```java
    @Entity  
    @Table(name="usertable")  
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")  
    @Searchable  
    public class User implements Serializable {  
          
        @GeneratedValue(generator="userIdSeq")  
        @SequenceGenerator(name="userIdSeq", sequenceName="usertable_id_seq")      
        @SearchableId  
        @Id  
        int id;  
          
        @SearchableProperty  
        String userId;                      // 'Unique identifier. It is formed using this fashion: ''prefix:identifier''  
        String userName;                    // Name used to log in the application.  
        String email;                       // User's email  
          
        @ManyToMany  
        @JoinTable( name="usergroup",  
                    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "userid", referencedColumnName="userId"),  
                    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "groupid")  
        )  
        List<Group> groups;  
          
        ...  
    }  
      
    // Group  
    @Entity  
    @Table(name="grouptable")  
    public class Group implements Serializable {  
        @Id  
        String groupId                  // Unique identifier for group.  
        String description              // Brief text describing the group purposes.  
          
        @ManyToMany(mappedBy="groups")  
        @Cascade(SAVE_UPDATE)  
        List<User> users  
      
        ....  
    }
```

On the database:
usertable (id, userId, name)
grouptable (id, description)
usergroup(userid, groupid, groupkey)

It's very satisfying to add Group to list of groups, call save method on User and watch hibernate save the usergoup togehter. However, I have a big problem of hibernate automatically deleting entry from the usergroup table automatically when I retrieve the User after a save(User) operation.

Here is the test sequence that generation the deletion of usergroup

1. save new user
2. save new group
3. And group to list in user
4. save user
5. get user from email

```java
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testGetUserByEmail(){
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession(); 
        
        String email = "sarah.silverman@comedycentral.com"; 
        User user = createUser(); 
        user.setWeCanContact(true); 
        user.setPartnersCanContact(false); 
        user.setAgreedTerms(false); 
        user.setReferer("Laura");
        
        String groupId = "AARP"; 
        String description = "Appletalk Address Resolution Protocol"; 
        Group group1 = new Group(); 
        group1.setGroupId(groupId); 
        group1.setDescription(description); 
        session.save(group1); 
        session.flush(); 
        user.getGroupLists().add(group1); 
        session.saveOrUpdate(user); 
        
        User testUser = userRepository.getUserByEmail(email);
        assertNotNull(testUser); 
        assertEquals("It's not the correct email", email, testUser.getEmail()); 
    }
```

```java
        private User createUser(){
            Session session = factory.getCurrentSession(); 
            String userId = "UB:2010"; 
            String userPassword = "sarah"; 
            String realName = "Sarah Silverman"; 
            String email = "sarah.silverman@comedycentral.com"; 
            
            User user = new User();
            user.setUserId(userId); 
            user.setUserName(email); 
            user.setUserPassword(userPassword); 
            user.setRealName(realName); 
            user.setEmail(email); 
            
            List<Group> emptyGroupLists = new ArrayList<Group>(); 
            user.setGroupLists(emptyGroupLists); 
            Group group = new Group(); 
            group.setGroupId("ABC"); 
            group.setDescription("A for apple");
            user.getGroupLists().add(group);
            session.save(group); 
            session.save(user); 
            
            session.flush();
            return user; 
        }
```

```java
// Repository Method to get user from email
// 
//  @NamedQuery(name="user.findByEmail",
//       query="SELECT u FROM User u " +
//    "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.groupLists " +
//              "WHERE upper(u.email) = :email")
    
public User getUserByEmail(String email) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
    Query query = session.getNamedQuery("user.findByEmail");
    query.setParameter("email", email.toUpperCase());
    User user = (User)query.uniqueResult();
    return user; 
}
```

Before executing step 5, usergroup with automatically removed like

**SQL outputHibernate:**

```sql
delete
    from
    usergroup
    where
    userid=?
```

A few thing I to note;

1. userid is NOT the pk of user object. Would that be the problem?
2. The manyTomany mapping in usergroup mapped by userid and groupid
3. It happens not just in Test. It's in development too.

How can I stop the automatic deletion of usergroup. Usergroup is very important table and should not be deleted. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnnyBeGood Unless you show your Test case, we can not help you.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for your response. Test case is added. Please let me know if I can clarify anything else. I have been trying with different @Casade option too. Thanks again.

Comment: You are a new user. Welcome, but if you see a useful answer, UPvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see User

```java
    public class User {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer id;

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name="USER_GROUP",  
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="GROUP_ID")
        )
        private List<Group> groupList = new ArrayList<Group>();

    }
```

Now our Group

```java
    public class Group {

        @Id
        private String id;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy="groupList")
        @Cascade(SAVE_UPDATE)
        private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

    }
```

Before going on, Let's see userList field in a nutshell

```java
    // Group.java

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="groupList")
    @Cascade(SAVE_UPDATE)
    private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
```

`@Cascade(SAVE_UPDATE)` means

> Save Or Update each referenced User

`mappedBy="groupList"` means

> For each REFERENCED user, see whether it has a reference to me (Group object). If so, set up our bidirectional relationship. So if you want to link User and Group through USER_GROUP table, each REFERENCED user has to have a reference to a Group object.

Now let's see what is happening in testGetUserByEmail method

```java
    Group group = new Group(); 
    group.setId(groupId);

    // group.getUserList(); returns a empty List, right ?
    // As there is no User with reference to group in group.getUserList();
    // So NO LINK between Group and User through USER_GROUP table
    session.save(group);

    // It explains why your link is missing
    // You need to set up both sides
    user.getGroupLists().add(group);

    // Just save a User
    // Nothing else
    session.saveOrUpdate(user);
```

In createUser method, you have the same scenario as shown above

So my advice is

> When using bidirectional relationship, ALWAYS use a add convenience method

```java
    // Group.java
    public void addUser(User user) {
        user.getGroupList().add(this);

        getUserList().add(user);
    }
```

```java
    // User.java
    public void addGroup(Group group) {
        group.getUserList().add(this);

        getGroupList().add(group);
    }
```

regards,

Comment: I dont think you answered his question: Why the delete command is issued? And how to avoid to the delete the oposite table (not the junction table)?