# Hibernate automatically deleting lines in table without expressly being told so? (@ManyToMany association, Spring JPA)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I am working on a Spring JPA, microservices-based project where I have two entities, UserEntity and RegionEntity, associated via a many-to-many relationship.
Below the (simplified) code for the two entities:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Audited
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "userId", columnDefinition = "int", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotAudited
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_regions",
            joinColumns        = @JoinColumn(name = "userId", columnDefinition = "int", nullable = false, updatable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "regionId", columnDefinition = "varchar(50)", nullable = false, updatable = false))
    private Set<RegionEntity> regions = new HashSet<>();
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"users"})
@Entity
@Table(name = "regions")
@Data
@Audited
public class RegionEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "varchar(50)", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "regions", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UserEntity> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Now, I have a route for persisting instances of a third entity, CallEntity, that makes use of both the previous entities. It may be useful to know that CallEntity has also a many-to-many association with RegionEntity, and a many-to-one with user.
Here's in short the method invoked by the route.

```
public CallDTO myMethod(String userName, /* ... more stuff */) {
    UserProjection userProj = userConsumer.findByUserName(userName, UserBasicProjection.class); // from another repository, retrieve a user projection
    UserEntity user = userRepository.findById(user.getId()).orElse(null); // use that projection to initialise the user
    Set<RegionEntity> userRegions = user != null ? user.getRegions() : null;
    CallEntity newCall = new CallEntity();
    / * some actions, mainly setting values for newCall using userRegions and user... */

    CallEntity call = callRepository.save(newCall);

    return callMapper.toDTO(call);
}
```

The problem is that Hibernate automatically deletes the lines related to the user-region pair in the associated table when saving the CallEntity object. So for example, if the user has an id of 1234 and has regions A, B and C associated,

```
user | region
-------------
1234 |   A
-------------
1234 |   B 
-------------
1234 |   C  
-------------
```

then all three lines will be deleted in the table after this line of code:

> CallEntity call = callRepository.save(newCall);

is executed.

This is the Hibernate version currently in use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the console printout after execution:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* get current state package-name.UserEntity */ select
        userent_.userId 
    from
        user userent_ 
    where
        userent_.userId=?
Hibernate: 
    /* get current state package-name.RegionEntity */ select
        regione_.name
    from
        region regione_ 
    where
        regione_.name=?
Hibernate: 
    /* insert package-name.CallEntity
        */ insert 
        into
            call
            (id, userid, regionid) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        last_insert_id()
Hibernate: 
    /* delete collection package-name.UserEntity.regions */ delete 
        from
            users_regions 
        where
            userId=?
Hibernate: 
    /* insert collection
        row package-name.CallEntity.userRegions */ insert 
        into
            call_region
            (id, name) 
        values
            (?, ?)
```

I found that if I change the direction of the relationship (the owning entity being, in this case, RegionEntity) the problem disappears. However, this is by no means a viable solution, as it would impact other parts of the project.
Also, I found that a similar question was asked before on this site ([ManyToMany assoicate delete join table entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080486/manytomany-assoicate-delete-join-table-entry)), but unfortunately the answer was not satisfactory. I tried adding and using convenience methods to correctly establish the association (as the answer from the linked question suggests), but that just didn't work.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Try removing the `mappedBy` in `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "regions", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`. This tells Hibernate that the relationship is managed on the `region` side

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem was solved by wrapping the set of regions in a copy.

That is, by replacing this line:

> Set userRegions = user != null ? user.getRegions() : null;

with:

> Set userRegions = userxpc != null ? Set.copyOf(userxpc.getRegions()) : null;